# Check for existing email in WooCommerce checkout using Ajax in the default "billing_email" field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Found this thread that is really close to my needs:

[Check for existing email in WooCommerce checkout using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343672/check-for-existing-email-in-woocommerce-checkout-using-ajax?newreg=89f76e79c13e46d8bc32c3fc9db8a907)

I used the code and it works perfect! I just have a little noob question.

How can I make this script work to my existing (default) Woocommerce "billing_email" field?

Maybe I just have to add some HTML to my field... But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I don't think billing_address have to be unique. Why do you want they be ? Could have multiple customers with the same address.

Comment: I'm very sorry... I want billing_email as unique... Editing the original post

Comment: So... getting things right. Can you guys help me to make my Woocommerce Default "billing_email" field work with this script?

Answer (score 0):

The Woocommerce default user registration do this check for you. No need to add anything. It already works as expected.

```
/**
 * Create a new customer.
 *
 * @param  string $email Customer email.
 * @param  string $username Customer username.
 * @param  string $password Customer password.
 * @return int|WP_Error Returns WP_Error on failure, Int (user ID) on success.
 */
function wc_create_new_customer( $email, $username = '', $password = '' ) {

    // Check the email address.
    if ( empty( $email ) || ! is_email( $email ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-invalid-email', __( 'Please provide a valid email address.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( email_exists( $email ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-email-exists', __( 'An account is already registered with your email address. Please login.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey JazZ, first of all, tks for your reply. What I'm trying to achieve is a Ajax verification as soon as the user fill the email address. The way it works by default just warns the user after he take some time filling all the fields and hit submit. I would like to warn that the user is already registered as soon as possible.